# How to set value if multiple data type is declared in model in Swift 5

Tags: json, model, swift5, xcode11, codable

```
class LBSModel: Codable {
let  unApproved: Int?
let backApproved : BackApproved
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case unApproved = "UnApproved"
    case backApproved = "BackApproved"
}
init(unApproved: Int?, backApproved: BackApproved) {
    self.unApproved = unApproved
    self.backApproved = backApproved
}
}

enum BackApproved: Codable {
case double(Double)
case int(Int)

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
        self = .double(x)
        return
    }
    if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
        self = .int(x)
        return
    }
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(BackApproved.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Available"))
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .double(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .int(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }
}
}
```

Actually I have model class declared valiable as Int type but from the server side some time come as Int value and some time comes Double, So I have declared these two data type for respective object].

Now I want to get value from BackApproved it can be int or double. I am using Codable protocol.
So how  to achieve this, Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have already know how to do this, as you have already done this once in `encode(to:)`. Use a switch statement. If it is `.double`, do something. If it is `.int`, do something else.

Comment: No no I am asking that how to get that value, I dont know its is double or Int like. object.backApproved likebecause it return BackApproved

Comment: Exactly, so you need to check whether it is a double or an int. And do different things in each case, just like you did in `encode(to:)`. There, you got that value as `x`.

Comment: Have some sample code for doing same thing

Comment: You've written the sample code yourself! Look at the `encode(to:)` method! See the two lines after each `case`? Replace those with whatever you want to do with the value `x`. And rather than `switch self`, you do `switch object.backApproved`.